# Unicode int to char, leading zero

Tags: python

I have an integer representing a unicode character which I want to transform to the actual character so I can print it out.

However the function unichr() gives me different behaviour depending on whether there a leading zero or not. (See screenshot below for a better explanation)

However, when the integer is stored in a variable I always get the first behavior whilst I want to achieve the second. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: A leading zero makes it an octal constant rather than decimal.

Comment: Today I learnt, thanks. That solved my question! :D